# Is it justifiable to block someone for posting a factually wrong but still clear question?

Tags: discussion

My question has in fact two parts.

- Does it mean you're blocked if you want to mention someone with a @ sign, but no sugesstions show up?
- Is it justifiable to block someone just because they have posted a factually wrong question? While the question still is clear and answerworthy.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way for one user to block notifications from another across the board, so your problem is likely just due to one of the technical limitations of pinging someone in a comment.

To start, there are [only a small set of people who can be notified with `@` in a given comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/274942), effectively just those who have already engaged with the post in some way (e.g. as author, commentor, etc.). This has always been in line with Stack Exchange's desire to distinguish itself from a social network and make interactions focus on content, rather than people (see for example, the rule of thumb to "vote for the post, not the person"). It's similar to the rationale for [not having a system for private messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/274942). Sure, sometimes this means that someone won't see a question that might be within their area of expertise or interest (although the odds are much lower on a site as small as our own). On the other hand, it has the additional advantages of allowing folks to choose how they engage and to avoid harassment.

If the person you're trying to notify falls into that notifiable set of users but still doesn't show up as pingable, check the FAQ I liked to above to see whether you're dealing with any of the problems that occasionally spring up (e.g. trying to notify multiple people, running into an issue caused by punctuation in a username, etc.).

Comment: The user I was trying to ping had commented on his answer on my question after I commented on his answer. I tried to ping him with @x format. But the entire user's name didn't show up to click. However, I wrote my comment with the @x before the body, but when the comment was posted, the @x disappeared!

Comment: @SnackExchange Ah, users are always notified of any comments on their own posts -- and because of the this, the system cuts off the leading @x to save some space. So they should have been notified even though you didn't see the popup.